# isset() is always returning false

Tags: php, forms, post, http-post

I have this php script which submits a form depending on the data sent from another form.
Here's my code:

```
function test($param)
{
   // second form
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
            <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='test' name='test$param'>
        </form>";
    if(isset($_POST["test$param"]))
    {
        echo "true";
    }
}

function test1()
{
    return 4;
}

function test2()
{
    for($x = 0; $x <= test1(); $x++)
    {
        test($x);
    }
}



// first form
echo "<form action='' method='post'>
        <input type=radio class=form-check-input value=opt1 name=opt1>opt1
        <input type=radio class=form-check-input value=opt2 name=opt2>opt2
        <input type=submit value=Submit name=submit>
        </form>";
if(isset($_POST["submit"]) && isset($_POST["opt1"]))
{
    test2();
}
```

When I submit the first form, the second one is displayed but the problem is the `if(isset($_POST["test$param"])` statement returns false(when I submit the second form there's no `true` printed).
Why might that be?

Answer (score 0):

PHP is likely getting confused because of the $ in the name attribute. Replace it with a _ and the code should run as expected.

Comment: Tried it and didn't work. I have another form that has an input with a $ and it works well, the problem is just when I try to submit a form depending on the data sent from anothe form

Comment: What about using ($var_name) instead of using the isset function?

Comment: you mean `if($_POST["test_$param"])` ?

Comment: Yes, you could also try something like:
`if(! $_POST["test_$param"] !== false)`

Answer (score 0):

### It won't echo true :

Because you're not calling the `test2()` function after submitting the second form. So none of the forms can be loaded.

### Concering $param :

You can try to concatenate the **$_POST** attribute 'test' with the **$param** using a dot (`.`) like so :

```
function test($param)
{
   // second form
    echo "<form action='' method='post'>
            <input class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='test' name='test".$param."'>
        </form>";
    if(isset($_POST["test".$param]))
    {
        echo "true";
    }
}
```

Make sure that **$param** is a **String** type.

Comment: $param is of type `int`, i used the `strval()` function to tarnsform it into an `str` and the form still doesn't echo `true`

Comment: It seems to be working by calling `test()` function and putting directly a parameter in it.

When you submit one of the five *test* forms, it won't call back `test2()` again, I think that's why it never returns 'true'

Answer (score 0):

Should be name=‘test”.$param.”’

Or prepare a variable before output of the form.

$param_name = ‘test_’ . $param;

And use
Name=“.$param_name.”